# Where is App_Start located?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I tried looking under: IIS Manager, but I only see:

```
StartPage
name
Applicationpools
Sites
  WebsiteName
```

I tried searching my physical C:\ drive for **App_Start** and found nothing

I tried searching my physical C:\ drive for **RouteConfig.cs** and found nothing

I'm just trying to find the Routes (i.e end-points) so I can edit them.

Comment: its generally in a global.asax(.cs) file.

Answer (score 0):

Once you expand Global.asax file, you will find .cs file which contains it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it's "published" (and) *compiled*, you won't find either/any (source code) `cs` files.

You'll need to get to the *source* project/solution.

Hth.